# ContextMenu throws a NullPointerException

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a ContextMenu within my InputMethodService.

it gets initiates as

```
private ContextMenu ContextMenuInfo = null;
```

then within OnLongClick it has

```
ContextMenuInfo.setHeaderTitle("hello!");
ContextMenuInfo.add("aaa!");
ContextMenuInfo.add("bbb!");                
mInputView.createContextMenu(ContextMenuInfo);
```

but it throws a NullPointerException. any ideas what might be missing?

Thanks!

edit:

tried with

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an option");
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Add to favorites");
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "See details");

}
```

and within the longclick

```
registerForContextMenu( v );
openContextMenu( v );
```

but they both give

**The method registerForContextMenu(View) is undefined for the type new View.OnLongClickListener(){}**

Comment: Where did you assign anything but null to ContextMenuInfo?

Comment: a... what else should be assigned besides setHeaderTitle and add ?

Comment: You need to go back to Chapter 1 on your book and read up how you instantiate an object.

Comment: in case you have already read it, don't keep it a secret. :)

Comment: I'm not going to teach you the whole bloody language in the comments.  You are missing one of the most fundamental concepts of the language - you need to go back to the beginning and learn it.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? From your code it appears that you are attempting to create a new Context Menu by clicking a context menu. What type of View are you trying to click to open the menu?

Comment: @Phil, what I'm trying to achieve is a context menu to appear when a button receives a long click ( linLayBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            Override
            public void onClick(View v) { )

Comment: @Roger, in that case, you should use a `Button` Object instead of trying to directly use a `ContextMenu` Object (see answer below).

Answer (score 3):

So... you set `ContextMenuInfo` as `null`, then you try to call methods on it and you get a `NullPointerException`. That shouldn't be surprising. You're essentially calling `null.setHeaderTitle("hello!");`.

Comment: Take a look at this document: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Answer (score 3):

In `onCreate()`, have the lines:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
registerForContextMenu(b);
```

Then, as you have, run these commands in onCreateContextMenu (or, more ideally, inflate the context menu from a resources xml file):

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

    menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an option");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Add to favorites");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "See details");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the registerForContextMenu(b) line still gives "The method registerForContextMenu(Button) is undefined for the type TotalKeyboard" :(  considering that "public class TotalKeyboard extends InputMethodService"

Comment: Are you trying to register the context menu in the `TotalKeyboard` class? The method will only work in an `Activity`, and the parameter must be a `View` Object, or a subclass of `View`.

Comment: [This](http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/04/android-context-menu-example-on-long-press-gridview/) blog may help out as well.

Comment: >>> The method will only work in an Activity <<< Ouch... any ideas what to do, since its an InputMethodService?

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work, but you could try moving `TotalKeyboard` to an *inner class* of your main `Activity`.

Comment: @Roger I recommend creating a new question for how to call `Activity` methods from an `InputMethodService`. You will get many more responses and hopefully a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods on a ContextMenuInfo object (or any object really) without instantiating it first.

[Link](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/using-context-menus-in-android/) for creating a context menu for a view.

Comment: Your errors here essentially result from a lack of understanding of how the Java language works, as well as how Android structure is developed.  I'd recommend brushing up on some of the basics of java, as well as reading through the how-to's on the android developers site.  There are full sections on how to create views and assign them context menus in the docs and examples.

Comment: Sorry, but where are this sections? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html here I find only the brief sample which I have above, it works for activities, not views. so if you can, please, give a quick tip how to fix this menu for a view. or what else is that forum for? every question can be answered by "go read a book". :/

Comment: The point we're trying to make by telling you to read a book is that you're going to keep running into these issues, and will keep asking questions until StackOverflow has basically coded the whole program for you...  Read tutorials online on how to develop an app from beginning to end.  The issue you have right now is not related to the context menu, but it is related to you passing in a clickListener to a method that expects a View.

Comment: could you please at least point to those tutorials, the ones I can find all are about menus for activities, not views.

Comment: I meant tutorials on entire apps, not just ones on views.  Notepad tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html

Comment: hmm, in the second part of this tutorial there is a context menu created, but still for an activity, rather the a view.